# Как обрезать строку в python до нужного символа с конца

Tags: python, строки

Дана строка:

```
a = 'Первый - второй - третий'
```

Как можно обрезать строку с конца до ' -', чтобы получилось:

```
'Первый - второй'
```

Раньше, когда в строке встречалось только одно ' - ' делал через .split(' - ') и удалял последний элемент под индексом [1], но как только встретились строки с двумя ' - ' это перестало корректно работать. Либо может можно также через .split(' - '), но удалять не конкретно [1], а просто последний элемент в полученном списке. Кто знает как сделать? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Можно использовать специальную питоновскую нотацию, которая позволяет обращаться с элементами из конца списка, используя отрицательные индексы.
В данном случае срез `[:-1]` берёт из списка все элементы, кроме последнего (минус первого в питоновской парадигме).

```
a = 'Первый - второй - третий'
print('-'.join(a.split('-')[:-1]))
```

Вывод:

```
Первый - второй
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло. Объясните, пожалуйста, зачем здесь `'-'.join` , просто попробовал без этого, чисто `a.split('-')[:-1]` такой же результат в итоге.

Comment: @ChikChirik У вас написано "Чтобы получилось: 'Первый - второй'" Если вам нужен просто список, то join не нужен, конечно, в этом случае получится: ['Первый ', ' второй ']. А если нужна в результате обратно строка с тире между словами, то нужен join элементов списка через тире. split разбивает строку на части, делая список, а join собирает обратно из списка строку.

Comment: Все понял, спасибо)

Answer (score 9):

```
a = 'Первый - второй - третий'
# Разбиваем строку по самому правому ' - ', берем левую часть
b = a.rpartition(' - ')[0]  
print(b)  # Первый - второй
```

- [`partition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) разбивает строку на три части: все что слева от
  разделителя, сам разделитель, то что справа от разделителя.

  Если разделитель не найден, то возвращается исходная строка и две пустых строки. Т.е. в любом случае возвращается кортеж из 3 элементов, поэтому дополнительные проверки наличия разделителя или длины результата (как при использовании `str.split()`) не нужны.
- [`rpartition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition) делает то же самое, но разбивает по самому правому разделителю. Если разделитель не найден, то возвращается две пустых строки и исходная строка.

Answer (score 4):

Вариант через метод поиска с конца [str.rfind](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind) и среза строки:

```
a = 'Первый - второй - третий'
i = a.rfind(' - ')
if i != -1:
    a = a[:i]
print(a)
# Первый - второй
```

Метод [str.rfind](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind) вернет индекса, но если не найдено то `-1`, поэтому нужна проверка.